# Proper name for $(window).blur()?

Tags: javascript, focus, onblur

I did an experiment online and want to describe in a paper that we recorded the times at which the participants left the experiment's tab or browser window by clicking elsewhere.

This is not strictly true because I actually recorded any `$(window).blur()` events, not just clicks outside the window.

Is there a proper name for this? How would you describe it in a scientific paper for a psychology audience who is most likely not familiar with JavaScript (or any other programming language)?

Comment: The window _lost focus_, _focus was lost_, stopped being in the _foreground_, no longer the _active_ window

Comment: @PaulS., thanks, but I think 'lost focus' is not too clear for somebody who doesn't know the .lostFocus() event.

Comment: if they're coming at it from a different programming language background which has any UI they probably are familiar with the concept of _focus_ (C#, delphi, Java, etc)

Comment: `lostFocus()` event is an invention. It doesn't exists. The explanation is that Paul S. said. If you go out of the current target is a lose of the focus

Comment: there is still [API docs](https://api.jquery.com/blur/) that say "The blur event is sent to an element when it loses focus"

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. @Marcos is right. The paper is written for psychologists who will most likely have no programming background. Edited this in the question. Thanks again for the answers

Comment: I'm unsure if StackOverflow is the right site for this question, given the target audience - the correct answer here as already discussed above is "lost focus".  The answer you're looking for _might_ (you need to check if it's on topic there) be better given on [ux.se] or maybe even [english.se].